# C Language: Search text file for a "word" and store the value into int and flout type variables

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

For example text file (vars.txt) contains:

```
var1
10
var2
3.54
var3
10110
```

I want to read the text file and store the value of var1 (which is the next line after var1 in text file) into a variable in my program.
I have the following code but seems not working:

```
char cBuffer[256];
FILE *pSrcFile;
pSrcFile = fopen("vars.txt","r");
while( (fgets( cBuffer, 256 , pSrcFile)) != NULL )
{
    if( strcmp( cBuffer, "var1" ) != NULL )
    {
        sscanf( pSrcFile, "%d" , &var1 );
        printf("var1 is found= %d",var1);
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I convert and save strings of a text file into int, flout, and binary type variables?

In other words, I want to search the text file to find "var1" and then save the next line (the value of "var1") to an integer variable and repeat this to search and store the value of "var2" into a float variable and "var3" into a binary variable an so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution of the problem with this code (thanks to the other answers). The code searches for the ***word*** and return the next ***value*** after word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int search_word_int( char *word , FILE *file , int *step )
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char dummy[strlen(word)+1];
    int step_ = step;
    int variable = 0;
    while((fgets(dummy, strlen(word)+1 , file)) != NULL )
    {
        if(strncmp(dummy, word, strlen(word)+1 ) == 0 )
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < step_ + 1 ; i++)
                fscanf(file, "%d" , &variable );
            printf("%s = %d\n",word,variable);
            break;
        }
    }
    return(variable);
}

float   search_word_float( char *word , FILE *file , int *step )
{
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char dummy[strlen(word)+1];
    int     step_ = step;
    float   variable = 0;
    while( (fgets( dummy , strlen(word)+1 , file )) != NULL )
    {
        if( strncmp(dummy, word, strlen(word)+1 ) == 0 )
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < step_ + 1 ; i++)
                fscanf( file , "%f" , &variable );
            printf("%s = %f\n",word,variable);
            break;
        }
    }
    return(variable);
}

int main()
{
    FILE    *file;
    file = fopen("vars.txt","r");
    int var1 = search_word_int( "var1" , file , 1 );
    float var2 = search_word_float( "var2" , file , 2 );
    fclose(file);
    return(0);
}
```

If text file ("vars.txt") is:

```
var1
10
var2     2.3
4.5
```

Then the result is:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = 4.5
```

Blank spaces, new line, and tab characters are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to read, write file:
//Read:

```
FILE *f1, *f2;
f1 = fopen("IN.INP","r");
fscanf(f1,"%d",&vars);    
fclose(f1);
//Write:
f2 = fopen("OUT.OUT", "w");
fprintf(f2, "%d",vars);
fclose(f2);
```

I'm not sure if I understand correctly about your question of "How to convert .txt to int,float,binary type vars" or not. But here is how:

```
char a = 10;
int b = (int) a;
```

But if you just want to read the .txt's value into int, float then just use
fscanf(f1,"%d",&vars);//d for int

Comment: `fscanf(f1,"%d",vars);` --> `fscanf(f1,"%d",&vars);`

Comment: My bad. Thank you

Comment: OK, it works. Thanks. I think the problem was sscanf, but instead, fscanf works!

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your pogram to work, check and understand what was missing.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

 char cBuffer[256]={'\0'};
 FILE *pSrcFile;

 pSrcFile = fopen("vars.txt","r");
 int var1;
 while((fgets(cBuffer, 256 , pSrcFile)) != NULL )
 {
    if(strncmp(cBuffer, "var1", sizeof("var1")-1 ) == 0 )
     {
       fscanf(pSrcFile, "%d" , &var1 );
       printf("var1 is found= %d\n",var1);
       break;
     }
  }
```

}

basically added strncmp() to avoid new line if any in bcBuffer, else it would not be equall so if() will not be true, it is not standard way of programming but crude way of making it working(all can't be explained here) .

Comment: @MajidRafei  really sorry then .. not sure any compiler trick,  i am seeing  
   output  as  "var1 is found= 10"     when I run this program

Comment: but, that really helped me. I have another problem though; I have make a sub-function for search and used your code in that. I opened the text file at the beginning of main() and do some search and close text file at the end of main(). It is seen that every time I call search() function and also fgets, it continues to get the next line (the next line after last call !), it does not start from the very beginning of the text file. How can i solve this? I want to read and search the text file from the beginning to find each "var".

Comment: thanks,if you want beging everytime from start, you have to use rewind() or fseek() API  to move file pointer to begining, so you have to call fseek like fseek(pSrcFile, 0L, SEEK_SET) ,  plz refer API documentation to known more about APIs